# How to encode the name of the LOOM programming language?

Tags: fonts, symbols

What symbols are used to write LOOM as shown in the image below? (The cutout is from a [paper](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.29.849) by Bruce et al., presented at the ECOOP conference in 1997.)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a simple `\mathcal{LOOM}` (in math mode of course). Different math fonts will give you (slightly?) different results.

You can define a macro for it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\LOOM}{%
    \ensuremath{\mathcal{LOOM}}\xspace
}
\begin{document}

... OO language, \LOOM.
\LOOM retains most of the features ...

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Note that `\ensuremath` is a little overkill here because you hardly use it inside math, so you can just use `$\mathcal{LOOM}$` instead. The `\xspace` adds a space after it if no punctuation mark follows.

Answer (score 1):

It's awful! However it's `$\mathcal{LOOM}$`

```
\newcommand{\LOOM}{$\mathcal{LOOM}$}
```

Just like all user defined commands without arguments one should remember to pay attention to a space following it:

```
\LOOM\ is a language ...
\LOOM{} is a language ...
A typical language is \LOOM.
```

It's possible to use `\xspace` to do the choice automatically.

However the [home page](http://www.isi.edu/isd/LOOM/) for the language uses simply "Loom", with no fancy letters.

Comment: Maybe `\ensuremath` might be safer?

Comment: Haha, I agree, it's awful =)

Comment: BTW: I think the home page you refer to is for a different "Loom" language.